# Where in Seoul can I rent a laptop?

Tags: electronic-items, rental, seoul

I am traveling in Seoul and my laptop died. Is there anywhere in Seoul where I could rent a laptop for a few weeks (Microsoft Windows or no OS)?

Comment: This http://forums.eslcafe.com/korea/viewtopic.php?p=918233 forum post suggests buying an older machine and that the price of such kills any short term rental market.

Comment: If you rent one, how can you be sure that all of your personal data is totally wiped off when you return it?

Comment: Well I shall not recommend it overtly, but how about purchasing it from MS Online Store and returning it before leaving? MS sets 4 weeks of a refundable period (and Apple has 2 weeks, FYI).

Comment: @Blaszard definitely a common option (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Returning&oldid=683603702#Fraudulent_returns : "In the United States, various abuses using the return process allegedly cost retailers more than $9 billion annually."). I believe returning items in South Korea in less common than in the US though, from what I have been told by locals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're unlikely to find a place to rent a laptop anywhere in the city, as that's not something most people are interested in. However it shouldn't be to hard to get a used laptop [from the local Craigslist](http://seoul.craigslist.co.kr/search/sys). Prices start from $100, depending on condition.